# Meeting someone in Canada then driving back to the USA, who is responsible for luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

Is it wise to be the passenger of a rental car going through customs if you don't know what's in your companion's luggage? Or does being passenger vs. driver not make any difference?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is a rental car or a personal car, doesn't matter if you are the passenger or the driver, if your travel companion is smuggling something you will end in hot water as well.

Comment: If you don't trust someone, don't travel with them

Answer (score 7):

Let's be realistic first and say we never **know** what's inside in our friends' luggage unless we packaged it ourselves. We can only guess.

And if your guess is that they have something in their package might get them in trouble with Customs - then it is unwise to be a passenger in their car. The Customs knows nothing about your relationship - and they won't take your word for that - so if certain contraband (drugs, weapons etc) is found you should expect to be at least detained. Especially if your "companion" claims the illicit stuff belonged to you. But usually Customs ask who the bag belongs to before opening them.

For Customs if contraband is found it only matters who possesses it - it doesn't really matter who was the driver or even car owner (unless contraband was hidden in dedicated car compartments which are not accessible to a passenger).

Saying so, most people go through Customs without any trouble, and do not bring contraband. Thus use your person assessment skills to see if you trust this person or not. They do have a potential to get you in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

At the land border, things are less cut and dried than by plane. Plane passengers have checked luggage that has their name on it. Their hand baggage is in their hand. Their pockets and such are easy to assign to a particular person. But in a car, if there is something in the glove compartment, whose is it? If there is something in the centre console, the trunk, under a floormat, whose is it?

I assure you **there is no simple rule like "it is always the driver."** If customs finds something, they investigate. Often, someone says "that's mine." If someone doesn't, then the only thing they can do is proceed as though all the people in the car conspired to bring this item in. There may be ways they can convince themselves whose it is and let one of the people go - I have certainly seen that on Border Security when pot was found in an RV.

I wouldn't worry about your driver's **luggage** - that is clearly identifiable as not yours. But if you're worrying about that, consider the entirety of the car, and the likelihood that the person giving you a ride would claim, if caught, that something was yours. If you really think that would happen, I recommend you find yourself another ride across the border.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers of personal cars are usually held responsible for the entire contents of the car, but if there's any doubt, most probably they will arrest both of you for smuggling.

If you don't trust your rider, then I would suggest that you buy them a bus ticket from Canada to the USA - along with all their luggage. The rules are different for common carriers such as buses and the passenger will be responsible for their own luggage.

Or have them UPS/FEDEX/mail their items to the USA under their own name.

Or as Jacob noted in comments, have them walk the land border by foot and meet them on the other side.

Comment: Or drive to a border crossing with a pedestrian crossing and then have your passenger walk across with their bags through the pedestrian crossing while you drive through and then meet them on the other side.